# Counting the number of distinct groups with and without repeat items

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, self-learning, multisets

Here's a simple question that popped into my head. I shouldn't be struggling with but am.

Suppose there are $n$ objects. We want to find the number of distinct groups.

First let's take the case where each of the $n$ objects is distinct. The number of distinct groups should be just $2^n$ right?

Here's where I get tripped up. Let's say all of the items are distinct except we have 1 item that is repeated. Let's say $\text{item}_1$ and $\text{item}_2$ are identical to each other. Well now the answer is not $2^n$ anymore because having $\text{item}_1$  and not $\text{item}_2$in my group is the same as having $\text{item}_2$ and not $\text{item}_1$. But having both and neither of the items should count as separate groups...

Does that make sense?

So let's break this into cases -

We have $\text{item}_1$ but not $\text{item}_2$. There are $2^{n-2}$ in this case because the number of distinct groups from the $n-2$ objects left is $2^{n-2}$

We have both $\text{item}_1$ and $\text{item}_2$. Again there are $2^{n-2}$ distinct groups in this case.

Now the case for neither of the items. Again there are $2^{n-2}$ distinct groups in this case.

We ignore the case where we have $\text{item}_2$ but not $\text{item}_1$ since we have already accounted for that in the first case and because the two items are identical.

How many distinct groups are there? There should be $3 (2^{n-2})$ since we just have to sum all three cases together.

**Is this correct? How would I expand this for the general case where I have $k$ identical objects of one item in n objects. How about if I had $k_1, ..., k_r$ identical objects for items $1, ..., r$ amongst the n objects.**

Going back to my example, I feel like back in highschool what I would do is just take the number of distinct n groups form before, $2^n$, and divide it by $2$ since I double counted one of the items. Why is this wrong or correct?

Also a general question - How can I tell when I've fully counted everything the correct number of times correctly. Any tips, resources, tricks and pointers are **greatly** appreciated. :)

Comment: Oh! and please tell me if my question doesn't make any sense. I will gladly edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to call these "sets" or "multisets" because "group" has a technical meaning in mathematics.

Suppose you have $c_k$ copies of each item $k$, and let $x_k \in \{0,\dots,c_k\}$ be the number of copies you select.  The choices are independent, and you have $c_k+1$ choices for each item, so the total number of distinct multisets is $$\prod_{k=1}^n (c_k+1).$$

In the special case $c_k=1$ (all items are distinct), this product simplifies to $$\prod_{k=1}^n (c_k+1)=\prod_{k=1}^n (1+1) = 2^n.$$

In the special case $c_1=0$, $c_2=2$, and $c_k=1$ for $k>2$, this product simplifies to $$\prod_{k=1}^n (c_k+1)=(0+1)(2+1)\prod_{k=3}^n (1+1) = 3\cdot 2^{n-2}.$$

In the special case $c_1=n$ and $c_k=0$ for $k>1$ (all items are the same), this product simplifies to $$\prod_{k=1}^n (c_k+1)=(n+1)\prod_{k=2}^n (0+1) = n+1.$$

By the way, the general formula also counts the number of divisors of an integer whose prime factorization is of the form $$p_1^{c_1} p_2^{c_2} \dots p_n^{c_n}.$$  The "items" are the primes, and the numbers of copies selected are the numbers of times each prime appears in the divisor.   See https://oeis.org/A000005.

Comment: Where does $x_k$ come into play? Should the product be $\Pi (x_k + 1)$ instead? Since $x_k$ is the number item k we want?

Comment: No, the product formula is correct.  The value of $x_k$ just reflects which of the $c_k+1$ choices you selected for item $k$.

Comment: Ooh! That makes sense! How would I change the formula to include $x_k$. So for example, I wanted $x_k = \frac{c_k}{2}$. So for all items I want half of them.

Comment: Oh wait! Then we would be over-counting if we changed the formula since the items are identical!! So no change right?

Comment: The case where it would matter what $x_k$ is is when I want at most $x_k$ items of item $k$. How would I modify the formula in this case?

Comment: You already have the value of $c_k$ to specify an upper bound on the number of copies of item $k$ that you are allowed to select.