# When the objects are not all distinct, the number of ways to select one or more objects from them is equal to : $(q_{1}+1)(q_{2}+1)\cdots (q_{t}+1) $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, factorial

Theorem : When the objects are not all distinct, the number of ways to select one or more objects from them is equal to :

$$(q_{1}+1)(q_{2}+1)\cdots (q_{t}+1) -1$$

where, there are $q_{1}$ objects of the 1st kind, $q_{2}$ objects of the second kind, ...$q_{t}$ objects of the t-th kind.

How to prove this theorem? I need hint/resource recommendation.

Comment: It is easier to count them if you count them include the case where you select zero items. Then do it by induction on $t.$

Comment: Have you tried setting $t$ equal to 2 or 3 and convincing yourself that the statement is true?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3935225/counting-the-number-of-distinct-groups-with-and-without-repeat-items/3935258#3935258

Comment: I notice that in your OP you write "I need hint/resource recommendation" and in your bounty request you write "I want a full derivation".  That reads as if you really just want someone to do the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Let there be $q_1$ objects of first kind, $q_2$ objects of second kind,... and  $q_t$ objects of $t^{th}$ kind.

To select at least one object from these, there is always a possibility that you don't select any object from one group, say the $i^{th}$ group ($1≤i≤t$). That's one way of selecting. Again, you may select $1$, $2$, ... or $q_i$ objects from the $i^{th}$ group. That's $q_i$ ways of selecting objects from the $i^{th}$ group. Thus, the total number of ways of selecting at least one object from the $i^{th}$ group is $q_i+1$.

The same procedure applies to groups $1$ through $t$.

Hence, the total number of ways of selecting at least one object from all those groups, is

$N=$ *product of ways of selecting from each group* $-1$

Therefore,
$$N=(q_1+1)(q_2+1)(q_3+1)...(q_t+1) -1$$

The $-1$ is there to eliminate the way, where you don't choose any object from any group.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. Apart from being against [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513), it is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their [assessed homework or exam](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33557/10513), so giving them the complete answer is unfair to the rest of their class.